# Unable to run mysql stored procedure from php code

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

I am not able to run MySQL stored procedure from PHP, no matter what I use. I am from .Net background and not well versant with PHP.

If I try the same query from PHP it doesn't work, whereas if I try in the SQL editor in PHPMyAdmin it works fine.

```
<?php
     $sql="SET @p0='".$path.$imageName."'; SET @p1='".$_SESSION['uid']."'; CALL `upload_image`(@p0, @p1);";
     $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>
```

and in Mysql Phpmyadmin tried this, which worked:-

```
SET @p0='images/user/Ganesh_1566681875.png'; SET @p1='1'; CALL `upload_image`(@p0, @p1);
```

and here is my stored procedure:-

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `upload_image`(IN `imagepath` VARCHAR(250), IN `userid` INT)
BEGIN
    UPDATE user SET profile_image_path = imagepath WHERE id = userid;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I must be able to run the stored procedure by passing value from PHP variables and it must update the database for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

I'm not sure why you're taking the approach you have. There is no need to assign values to variables first, you can simply call the procedure directly e.g.

```
$sql = "CALL `upload_image`('$path.$imageName', $_SESSION['uid'])";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Regardless, it would be far preferable to use prepared statements to protect yourself from SQL injection. Something like this:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("CALL `upload_image(?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $path.$imageName, $_SESSION['uid']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Additionally, your stored procedure being only one statement means that it would be more optimal to just execute that statement directly:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE user SET profile_image_path = ? WHERE id = ?;");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $path.$imageName, $_SESSION['uid']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

**Original Answer**

Your problem is that you are trying to run three separate queries (each `SET` counts as a query), which `mysqli_query` doesn't support. You have two options, you can use [`mysqli_multi_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php):

```
 $sql="SET @p0='".$path.$imageName."'; SET @p1='".$_SESSION['uid']."'; CALL `upload_image`(@p0, @p1);";
 $result = mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql);
```

Or you can run them as three separate queries:

```
 $sql="SET @p0='".$path.$imageName."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 $sql="SET @p1='".$_SESSION['uid']."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 $sql="CALL `upload_image`(@p0, @p1)";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

The latter is probably preferred as `mysqli_multi_query` makes you more vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks,
but will that not be inefficient as it takes more queries than required ?. and what if I wanted to update many fields, can you please suggest a better alternative?

Comment: The better alternative is to get rid of this stored procedure crap and use a regular query with prepared statements.

Comment: @YourCommonSense sometimes I miss the forest for the trees. I've updated the answer.